# ClickHouse TTL settings with WHERE condition

Tags: data-warehouse, clickhouse, ttl

I have a table with the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE default.pricing_rate_latest_state_union_test
(
    `organization_id`   Int32,
    `organization_name` String,
    `scraping_time`     AggregateFunction(max, DateTime),
    `amount_from_raw`   Float64,
    `amount_to_raw`     Float64,
    `key_param_id`      LowCardinality(String),
    `amount_from`       AggregateFunction(argMax, Float64, DateTime),
    `amount_to`         AggregateFunction(argMax, Float64, DateTime),
    `source`            LowCardinality(String)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/*****/pricing_rate_latest_state_union_test',
 '{replica}')
ORDER BY (key_param_id,
 amount_from_raw,
 amount_to_raw)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

For which I would like to add a TTL expression on scraping_time column, so that after certain number of days the corresponding records are dropped. This I can do easily with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE default.pricing_rate_latest_state_union_test 
MODIFY TTL finalizeAggregation(scraping_time) + INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

This is works fine, but my end goal is to add condition describing which rows need to be deleted after expiration. What I'm trying is this:

```
ALTER TABLE default.pricing_rate_latest_state_union_test 
MODIFY TTL finalizeAggregation(scraping_time) + INTERVAL 30 DAY 
DELETE WHERE source = 'some_value';
```

Unfortunately this lead to the following error:

```
 DB::Exception: Exception happened during execution of mutation '0000000000' with part 'all_0_0_0' reason: 'Code: 10, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Not found column scraping_time in block. There are only columns: organization_id (version 21.8.13.6 (official build))'. This error maybe retryable or not. In case of unretryable error, mutation can be killed with KILL MUTATION query
```

According to this [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#use-of-index-for-partially-monotonic-primary-keys) it should be possible as there is the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_with_where
(
    d DateTime,
    a Int
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(d)
ORDER BY d
TTL d + INTERVAL 1 MONTH DELETE WHERE toDayOfWeek(d) = 1;
```

I believe my case doesn't work that smoothly due to the ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree, so any help would be greatly appreciated here.

I'm also interested in the meaning of *Not found column scraping_time in block.* I know what part is in ClickHouse, but what is the block and why it doesn't see the *scraping_time*, but see the *organization_id*?

Answer (score 1):

While investigating this case found that problem is not in AggregateFunction. Problem is that Clickhouse's TTL doesn't support WHERE clause in MODIFY TTL statement when table is not empty.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `scraping_time` AggregateFunction(max,
 DateTime),
    `source` String
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/test',
 '{replica}')
ORDER BY (source)
TTL finalizeAggregation(scraping_time) + toIntervalDay(if(source='condition1', 30, 40)) where source <> 'condition2'
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

This works. After fill that table. Then if you will try to remove TTL and add again through MODIFY it will raise error described above.

```
ALTER TABLE test REMOVE TTL;

ALTER TABLE test MODIFY TTL scraping_time + toIntervalDay(if(source='scraper', 30, 40)) where source <> 'stable';
```

> SQL Error [341]: ClickHouse exception, code: 341, host:
> *****************, port: ****; Code: 341,
> e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Exception happened during execution
> of mutation '0000000000' with part 'all_0_0_0' reason: 'Code: 10,
> e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Not found column scraping_time in
> block. There are only columns: organization_id (version 21.8.14.5
> (official build))'. This error maybe retryable or not. In case of
> unretryable error, mutation can be killed with KILL MUTATION query
> (version 21.8.14.5 (official build))

I've tried to remove WHERE and it works.

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY TTL finalizeAggregation(scraping_time) + toIntervalDay(if(source='condition1', 30, 40));
```

So here are three **SOLUTIONS**:

**1. As described by Denny Crane to don't use WHERE when you are MODIFY'ing TTL, you can replace it with multiIf or multiple ifs**

**2. Copy data to temp table, truncate table in which you want to add TTL, add that TTL ( must work with WHERE statement), copy data back to main table**.

**3. Not recommended. Drop table and then recreate with your TTL in CREATE statement**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug or unexpected behavior because TTL is not designed to work with AggregateFunction.

You can construct TTL without WHERE

```
ALTER TABLE default.pricing_rate_latest_state_union_test  
  MODIFY TTL if (source = 'some_value', finalizeAggregation(scraping_time) + INTERVAL 30 DAY, toDateTime(0));
```